# writing new data structure

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory

I have in my homework some question about data structure:

I have elements which consist of two fields

```
class Element{
int point;       // point on the ax
int height;
};
```

I need to write data structure with the following interface:

```
**Init(N)** - any complexity You want, initialization of N elements
**Update(x,y)** - if element on the point x exists, change its height to the y, complexity O(logn)
**Highest(x)** - find the highest element on the left from the element x and on the right of the element, `complexity I need is also O(logn)`

complexity for the memory is O(n)
```

can somebody please help, how can I create function `Highest` with `current complexity`? thanks in advance for any help.

```
P.S I can use hash tables and also AVL trees
```

#### edited

thank You for all of you guys, I can't get one small thing, how to store data:

```
            10,1
     |               |
     5,14           17,23
|         |      |        |
2,5       7,25  5,10    20,100

    this is my tree all keys are the points on the ax X, number after comma is the height;
    if I want for example to find the highest on the right from NODE (2,5), I need to pass 
all nodes till the (20,100), cause this one is highest, am I wrong?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AVL tree to find the element x and find the largest value in its left subtree and right subtree.  So just walk down right until you can't and that will be the largest element in the subtree.  Do that for the left and right branch and it should run in O(logn)

EDITED:
So in response to your edited question, going off of how you're interpreting the question, wouldn't it make more sense to just find the largest element in the tree in general?  If the node x that you call method on is not the highest, then the highest to the right will just be the largest element in the tree. Finding the largest takes O(log n) time.

Comment: @user479988: sorry, but don't understand, if for example I need to find left highest of the lats element on the ax, I need to check all elements on the left, and it is not log(n) am I wrong?

Comment: well on the left subtree you would just keep walking right and when you can't walk right anymore, then that element will be the largest.  Since it's an avl tree, the tree is balanced so it should take log(n).

Comment: @rookie: You can assume that you have a subtree with your left node as a root. Now, what would be the complexity for finding a max in that tree. Same as finding max in any AVL tree -> log(n) :D

Comment: If you add sorted list to AVL tree you'll get linear list and you'll get  O(n) complexity. If you'll add shuffled data to tree, you'll get correct complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Higest(x) with log(n) gives answer about AVL trees

Comment: sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: Hash tables are not sorted in the nature. So you have to check all elements to find higest